# Make rows locked to never break row in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to make all my cells/rows in excel locked to never be taller than "one row". To clarify, never break line.

As you can see in the picture, row nr 1 is perfect and thats what I want. I got this sheet from my work. When I try to add my own line, it happends like row 2 in the picture. How do I make it locked like row nr 1?

Sidenote. When I push backspace on row 2 to remove that gap above the numbers, row 3 is the result. Quite odd.

Im an excel noob but need some desperate help here.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try just highlighting all cells, and going to the Home menu, along the top, and unmarking "Wrap Text". If you're in a previous version, just find how to not set the formatting to "Wrap Text".  (This assumes your data doesn't have line breaks in the cell itself).

Comment: This is what I thought would work great. Thanks for the idea. But the problem is that once you double click on that cell, it goes back to unwrapping. I want permanent wrapping. And the numbers that dont fit to overlap into the next cell once i doubleclick to see them all.

Comment: Im an idiot, this seems to work fine. The problem was that I had a line break in the text, so thats why it went back to linebreakmode when i doubleclicked.